# Workaround/s to expose derived types' properties using OData

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, derived-types

We want to expose the properties of our derived types with OData and we are using Entity Framework.  But we always have the exception that we cannot access the navigation properties of those derived types.  We can't do it with service operations as well.  Now, we are thinking if we can customize the response just to show the properties of our derived entities particularly the navigation properties.  What are the possible workarounds?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Derived Types" in more detail.

Comment: Derived types are types which derived from a base type.  For example, we have a Employee class.  Then, there are other classes that derived from that class such as Administrator and Staff.  Btw, we are going to restructure our model since WCF Data Services is not yet supporting access for derived types' navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the base type collection entries to the derived type in odatav3 with this format

```
<root>/<base collection name>/<full namespace of derived type>
```